# How to get target OS type in Testinfra when running a test remotely?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

Within [Testinfra](https://github.com/philpep/testinfra), how can I create a test condition for the target operating system (if at all)?

I'd like to run the test on `target` host through:

```
$ testinfra -v --host=target test.py
```

I tried:

```
def test_passwd_file(File):
    passwd = File("/etc/passwd")
    if SystemInfo.type == "darwin"
        assert passwd.group == "wheel"
```

I tried:

```
if SystemInfo.type == "darwin"
    def test_passwd_file(File):
        passwd = File("/etc/passwd")
        assert passwd.group == "wheel"
```

But these were basically shots in the dark, due to lack of examples and documentation, and did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had kinda the same problem, but solved it like this when I took a better look at this part: http://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#test-docker-images

I have in my test file:

    <strike>import testinfra</strike>

```
os = testinfra.get_backend(
  "local://"
).get_module("SystemInfo").distribution

def test_zabbix_package(Package):
    zabbixagent = Package('zabbix-agent')
    assert zabbixagent.is_installed

    if os == 'centos':
        assert zabbixagent.version.startswith("3.0")
    elif os == 'debian':
        assert zabbixagent.version.startswith("1:3.0")
```

First import the 'testinfra' module.
Create the os variable by executing the `testinfra_get_backend` module. In my case I had to run the `SystemInfo` module with the `distribution` function.

In the test I can make use of the `os` variable and use it in a if statement.

For your problem, I would like to suggest it like this:

    import testinfra

```
os = testinfra.get_backend(
  "local://"
).get_module("SystemInfo").type

def test_passwd_file(File):
    passwd = File("/etc/passwd")
    if os == "darwin":
        assert passwd.group == "wheel"
```

Edit:
I've re-editted my Answer, As SO wants this.

I have the following working now for my role for Zabbix Agent:

```
def test_zabbix_package(Package, SystemInfo):
    zabbixagent = Package('zabbix-agent')
    assert zabbixagent.is_installed

    if SystemInfo.distribution == 'debian':
        assert zabbixagent.version.startswith("1:3.0")
    if SystemInfo.distribution == 'centos':
        assert zabbixagent.version.startswith("3.0")
```

This works on both the Debian and CentOS container.

```
def test_passwd_file(File, SystemInfo):
    passwd = File("/etc/passwd")
    if SystemInfo.type == "darwin":
        assert passwd.group == "wheel"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ah, my bad. I use a centos host of a centos docker container. I too use it with Molecule and was searching a way to make it OS dependable. Have to search a little further to make it work. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Me again. I checked how TestInfra is doing their own checks: https://github.com/philpep/testinfra/blob/master/testinfra/test/test_modules.py  You can use: def test_passwd_file(File, SystemInfo): and do something like: SystemInfo.type == 'darwin' in the function.